# Having issues when executing shell script via crontab

Tags: shell, cron

I have scheduled a job in crontab to run on every last Friday of the month, it never runs and gives me error as

> /bin/sh: line 0: [: missing `]'

However, it works when I run the shell script manually.

why am I getting this error?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete shell script and the crontab definition.

Comment: It may also help to read thru https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info . Good luck.

Comment: Cron is running it with different shell than you are?